# Image uploads with imgur.com currently down

Tags: bug, status-completed, images, error-message, imgur

When I try to insert an image using the upload tool, I get:

[image: Failed to upload image, please try again!]
<sub>(source: [mrozekma.com](http://so.mrozekma.com/imgur-broken.png))</sub>

I'm running the current version of Chrome on Windows, with a number of SE-related user-scripts. Confirmed by several other users, so not just me.

Comment: Yes, stack.imgur.com appears to be down.

Comment: yeah, existing images are also not being served

Comment: @Sathya, that'd be far more serious, but I am not seeing it.

Comment: @Oddthinking [example](http://superuser.com/questions/317916/is-it-possible-to-get-back-data-from-a-micro-sd-which-is-unresponsive) http://i.imgur.com/RgbLx.png

Comment: Yep, just happened to me also.

Comment: Yup, existing images aren't being served across the network. I repro on SO as well as the SU example Sathya's given. I suspect this is a problem on imgur's end, not something the SE devs can fix.

Comment: @Sathya, you are right - for some images. This one is working fine for me: http://i.stack.imgur.com/TiPqj.png although caching may be a factor. Yes, that seems more important.

Comment: Its happening again, and looks like it has been disabled again...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yep, looks like a problem with uploads to stack.imgur.com -- we've contacted them via email and phone, and have disabled uploading for now until they can get it fixed.

edit: looks like they fixed it, so we're re-enabling uploads now.

Answer (score 2):

Failing for me as well...

[image: fail screenshot]

-- I used the actual [imgur website](http://imgur.com) to upload this image :D

Comment: Going to imgur.com to upload images? What are we, savages?

Comment: @Michael, it's funny, the first thing I did was type in image host etc into Google forgetting that they might host images outside of SE...if that's not a fail in brand awareness, I don't know what is.