# Why is imgur rejecting requests from SE websites?

Tags: bug, status-completed, imgur

I can't seem to post any images from any SE website. I get the error below. The uploader on their website seems to work fine as I uploaded the screen shot there.

[image]

Comment: I'm counting down the five months until [Stack Exchange's current agreement with Imgur](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/94286/134300) expires...

Comment: @Jeremy But then we'll only have about 6 months until the world ends. Hmph.

Answer (score 9):

Imgur was having storage issues again. We just got a mail assuring us that everything should be back up now.

The reason for that particular message is just that they're returning a 503 status code. And since that's not listed in their [list of errors the API may return](https://api.imgur.com/error_handling), you're getting our [catch-all error message](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/81400/there-should-be-a-more-descriptive-error-on-image-uploading-failures/101450#101450).

I'll add the 503 response to the list of responses that cause the "an error occured at imgur" message, that's more fitting in probably all cases.

Comment: … so we don't have to blame you guys ;)

Comment: Thanks for the answer! :D Perhaps you should have it say "A unicorn tried to divide by zero with the guys at imgur and the resulting argument was invalid."