# Error message when attempting to upload images from Wikipedia

Tags: bug, images, uploader

I've recently had an issue adding images to posts that I've sourced from Wikipedia. I can upload them without issue when I download them and upload them from my computer but I can not upload them using the "from the web" option. I get the error message:

> Failed to upload image; the format is not supported

Seeing as I can upload them from a computer without issue, it's not actually the format so much as it's the URL or the server on one side or the other acting up.

As an example, I have this issue with both of the images on this article about [Hank (textile)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hank_(textile)).

I was able to successfully upload the top image after downloading it to use in an [answer on Arts & Crafts](https://crafts.stackexchange.com/a/3189/52) but could not add it directly from the link.

I know this isn't the first time I've experienced this but I'm not sure if it's **all** Wikipedia images or just some of them.

It's possibly related to [Error messages when uploading an image "from the web"](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/130633/error-messages-when-uploading-an-image-from-the-web) but that one is a FR and it's not specific to Wikipedia so I'm not sure it's the same thing.

If it is Wikipedia blocking the upload for some reason, it'd be good to know if it's intentional as I might consider getting images from elsewhere.

Comment: I'm 51% sure the uploader doesn't accept SVG, which is a common format on Wikipedia, noting that sometimes when you download them you get the PNG version depending on how you download them, since many wikipedia links yield rendered PNG forms of the SVG images, which could possibly explain the successes. Then again I've never tried to upload SVG locally, so take this comment with a big disclaimer.

Comment: The link says "png", `https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/a/ad/Yarn_hank_uncoiled.png/220px-Yarn_hank_uncoiled.png` - It also works just fine in chat... so I'm not sure that's necessarily the issue?

Comment: As far as SVGs go, there you are correct... According to an answer [here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/92568/allow-svg-image-uploads) imgur requires raster images and SVG is vector.

Comment: I get a 404 for that url in the browser, I think it's supposed to be `https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/a/ad/Yarn_hank_uncoiled.png` (that doesn't fix the problem, but just fyi).

Comment: Quick solution, though it doesn't answer the issue: Copy the image (not the URL) and paste it (Ctrl+V) on the image uploader instead. It worked on those images just like when you download them first.

Comment: This error's blocking my uploads, too - noting that I'm also using the PNG formats.